# Angularjs $routeprovider config using services

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-ui-router

My application is created by using `MVC 4 + AngularJs`.

In this application we are using Bundling for render the javaScript and css files, this is working as expected.

But for the `$routeProvider` we are using `templateUrl` to load the template in runtime, but the speed of page is decreased.

For the reason i have created the below folder structure:

```
HTML
    Home
       Index.html
       Xyz.html
    Student
       Create.html
       Update.html
```

> I want to render these files using the bundling like below:

```
  [
    {
      key:"/HTML/Home/Index.html",
      val:"HTML text"
    },
    {
      key:"/HTML/Home/Xyz.html",
      val:"HTML text"
    },
    {
      key:"/HTML/Student/Create.html",
      val:"HTML text"
    },
    {
      key:"/HTML/Student/Update.html",
      val:"HTML text"
    }
]
```

> In that case we use `$templatecache` and caches all the key with values 
>   and then we can able to use like below:

```
 $routeProvider.
     when('/Home', {
          template: $templatecache.get("/HTML/Student/Update.html"),
          controller: 'HomeController'
      }).
      when('/planning', {
          template: '$templatecache.get("/HTML/Student/Create.html"),
          controller: 'StudentController'
      }).
      otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/Home'
      });
```

> This is taking long time in initial load, after that it loading fast.
>
> 1. How can we render template using bundling?
> 2. How to put html in `$templatecache` (using services or other)?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question. You bundle only javascript and css so html templates would't affect the bundling

Comment: i am use bundle for javascript and css and i want use this for render html file also.

so i am able to use like 

forEach(var t in htmlTeml){
$templatecache.put(t.key,t.Val)
}